# How to prove $e^{\sqrt 2}>3$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality, exponential-function

> How to prove $e^{\sqrt 2}>3$?

If I know the fact that $\sqrt{2}>\log(3)$, then the result follows (because $e^{x}$ is increasing). Can you give different solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$$\log(3) = \int_{1}^{3}\frac{dx}{x}\stackrel{CS}{\leq}\sqrt{\int_{1}^{3}\,dx\int_{1}^{3}\frac{dx}{x^2}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}<\sqrt{2}.$$
CS stands for *Cauchy-Schwarz*, of course.

Answer (score 17):

$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\cdots$, plug in $x=\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: You don't even need the term $x^3/6$.

Comment: Very nice idea.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach uses the fact that for any positive $x$ and $n\rightarrow +\infty$, the expression

$(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$

strictly increases monotonically as a function of $n$ to $e^x$.  Then put in $x=\sqrt{2}, n=3$ to get

$e^{\sqrt{2}}>(1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3})^3$

$(1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3})^3=1+\sqrt{2}+\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{27}>1+\sqrt{2}+\frac{2}{3}>3$

where the last inequality in the chain is proved from $2>(16/9)$ thus $\sqrt{2}>(4/3)$.

Comment: You may need to use "strictly increases" rather than just "increases" to prevent things like "greater but not strictly greater".

Comment: Approved the edit, but there never was a chance of the inequality being saturated.  The binomial power expansion is,strictly greater than the sum of the first three terms and the square root of $2$ is strictly greater than $(4/3)$.

Answer (score 3):

For all $x$ such that $1 \leqslant x \leqslant 3$ we have $x(4 - x) = 4 - (x - 2)^2 \leqslant 3$, whence
$$
\log3 = \int_1^3\frac{dx}{x} \leqslant \int_1^3 \frac{4 - x}{3}\,dx = \frac{4}{3} < \sqrt{2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

A well-known inequality states that $\log(1 + x) < x$ for $x > -1$ and $x \ne 0$. Taking $x = 1/4$,
$$
\log3 < \log\frac{3125}{1024} = \log\frac{5^5}{4^5} = 5\log\frac{5}{4} = 5\log\left(1 + \frac{1}{4}\right) < \frac{5}{4} < \sqrt{2}.
$$